# JavaScript: "Uncaught TypeError: item[key].includes is not a function"

Tags: javascript

```
const filters = { prop1: 'abc' };

const items= [{
       prop1: 'abc',
       prop2: 'def',
       prop3: {
           prop4: '123',
           prop5: '456',
       }
    }];
```

I programmed a function to filter the data based on the passed objects in the `filters` variable. It works fine.

```
const onFilterData = (
    items,
    filters) => {
    return items.filter((item) => {
        return Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
            item[key].includes(value),
        );
    });
}
```

Expanding the logic also involves filtering by objects within the object. For example, I would like to filter in this way as well:

```
const filters = { prop1: 'abc', prop3: '456' };
```

It should return the same result, since `prop3` contains one of the values `456`.
Unfortunately returns an error:

`"Uncaught TypeError: item[key].includes is not a function"`

---

I started modifying this function and did something like this:

```
const onFilterData = (
    items,
    filters) => {
    return items.filter((item) => {
            let isExist = false;
            const { prop3, ...otherProps } = filters;
        
        if (prop3) {
                isExist = Object.values(item.prop3).toString().includes(prop3);
        }
    
        isExist = Object.entries(otherProps).every(([key, value]) =>
            (item[key]).includes(value),
        );
        
        return isExist;
    });
}
```

This is even a good solution, but it does not work correctly because if I do something like this:

```
const filters = { prop1: 'abc', prop3: '4dad23das56' };
```

it will still return the same result, and there is no such object in the `items` array.

Comment: Check if item[key] exist first

Comment: @Lk77 it's not about solving this problem only about modifying the function to allow filtering also the object one below.

Comment: @Lk77 of course I know that I can: `[(item[key])].includes(value)` but I want to keep the property of searching by string (so that it works like like in sql)

Comment: So you want to get all objects that match the given properties and values ?

Comment: @Lk77 yes, including values of `props3`

Comment: But props3 is an object, there is no includes function on it, if you want to test against all values of the object, without the keys, you can do `Array.from(object)`. You will need to check if it's an object first : `if(typeof item[key] == 'object'){ return Array.from(item[key]).includes(value) }`